# Order of data in plist file?

Tags: ios

Below is my plist file. When I pull out those inner dictionaries and display them, they are only displayed alphabetically BUT I would want them to be pulled out as they are in the plist and then be able to append another inner dictionary OR order the existing ones. Is there another better approach for what i'm trying to do?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>z-key</key>
    <dict><key></key><string></string></dict>
    <key>a-key</key>
    <dict><key></key><string></string></dict>
    key>k-key</key>
    <dict><key></key><string></string></dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Many thanks, Bilal

Answer (score 0):

Make the top level container an array instead of a dictionary. Arrays are ordered, dictionaries are not.